# UITableView make 1 section for every day from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Im stuck with this problem, I have a UITableView and i populate it with data from an NSMutableArray. The Array has the following structure:

```
<array>
<dict>
    <key>Date</key>
    <string>2011.18.09 04:17 PM</string>
    <key>Value</key>
    <string>58.00</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <string>2011.15.09 04:21 PM</string>
    <key>Value</key>
    <string>0.00</string>
</dict>
</array>
```

I would like to have a section for each day in the Array. I already figured out how to return the number of dates, and name the section headers, the only problem i am having is returning the number of rows per section and then defining the cells for each row.

Working code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedData.daf"];
NSMutableArray *d = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *test = [d valueForKey:@"Date"];
NSString *g = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] init];
c = 0;
    for (g in test) {
        s = [g substringToIndex:[g length]-9];
        if (![s isEqualToString:sf]) {
            c = c+1;
            [dates addObject:s];
        }
        sf = [g substringToIndex:[g length]-9];
    }
return c;
```

that code counts the different dates and creates an array with the section names. Could anybody help me with defining the number of rows (by counting the number of objects for each day) and by giving the rows the right value in the ´cellForRowAtIndexPath´ method.

Comment: just a side comment but g and s will leak every time you call this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i finally found a solution. It is actually pretty easy to understand. To return the numbers of sections, i need to find out how many different dates there are in the array. For the number of rows i need to know how many values there are for each day. so here is what i did:

Rows:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedData.daf"];
    NSMutableArray *d = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *jes = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    count = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *before = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *after = [[NSString alloc] init];
    jes = [d valueForKey:@"Date"];
    int ja = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i<=[jes count];i++) {
        ja = ja+1;
        before = [jes objectAtIndex:ja];
        if (![before isEqualToString:after]) {
            NSCountedSet *ca = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:jes];
            int f = [ca countForObject:before];
            [count addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",f]];
        }
        after = before;
    }
    return [[count objectAtIndex:section] intValue];
}
```

Sections:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedData.daf"];
    NSMutableArray *d = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *jes = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    count = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *before = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *after = [[NSString alloc] init];
    jes = [d valueForKey:@"Date"];
    int ja = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i<=[jes count];i++) {
        ja = ja+1;
        before = [jes objectAtIndex:ja];
        if (![before isEqualToString:after]) {
            NSCountedSet *ca = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:jes];
            int f = [ca countForObject:before];
            [count addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",f]];
        }
        after = before;
    }
    return [count count];
}
```

Titles:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedData.daf"];
    NSMutableArray *d = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableArray *test = [d valueForKey:@"Date"];
    NSString *g = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *sf = [[NSString alloc] init];
    dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    c = 0;
    for (g in test) {
        s = [g substringToIndex:[g length]-9];
        if (![s isEqualToString:sf]) {
            c = c+1;
            [dates addObject:s];
        }
        sf = [g substringToIndex:[g length]-9];
    }
    return [dates objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't `alloc` and `init` g and s in the code above, this is not necessary and is causing a memory leak.

I would pass through your array and create a second array containing dictionaries. Each dictionary would hold two objects, one date and one array. The array would hold all of the values applicable to each date.

Using this technique, the count of the main array would be the number of sections, and the rows per section would be the count of the array held within the dictionary. The value for each row would be the object at the appropriate index for the section (main array) and row (inner array).

Here is some very slightly tested code which may do what you want:

```
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"test.plist"];
    [array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Date" ascending:YES]]];

    NSMutableArray *datesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
    NSString *previousDate = @"";
    NSMutableArray *currentDateValues;

    for (NSDictionary * dict in array)
    {
        if ([[[dict objectForKey:@"Date"] substringToIndex:10] isEqualToString:previousDate])
        {
            // This is another entry from the same date
            [currentDateValues addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"Value"]];
        }
        else
        {
            // We haven't seen this date before
            previousDate = [[dict objectForKey:@"Date"] substringToIndex:10];
            currentDateValues = [NSMutableArray array];
            [currentDateValues addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"Value"]];
            NSDictionary *newDate = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:previousDate,@"Date",currentDateValues,@"Values", nil];
            [datesList addObject:newDate];
        }
    }
```

This should leave you with one array, `datesList`, which holds a dictionary for each date and an array of all the values for each date.

Comment: could you help me with that? I can't get it to work properly!

Comment: Update the question with what you have, and I'll do my best.

Comment: also, im trying to do it by myself, i need to count how often a value exists in a nsdictionary in nsmutablearray, for example if the dict is `key = hello, key = hello, key = bye, key = bye, key = bye` how can I count how many times the value for `key`is bye and how many times it is hello?

Comment: For the question, if you put in the code you currently have to try and separate out the array.